# Output Value conversion in PHP

Tags: php

I am getting Output value like `0.000098`, `0.000854`.

But I need `98`, `854` instead.

How to do this?

Comment: how come 0.000098 == 98?

Comment: Why do you need this in the first place?

Comment: Just display the value

Comment: `echo $number * 1000000;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$str = '0.00009801';
$r = array();
$ret = preg_match('/[1-9]+[0-9]+/', $str, $r);
echo $r[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function convertVal($value) {

   for($i=0;$i<strlen($value);$i++){  
        $a = strpos($value,substr($value,$i,$i+1));

        if($a>0){
            $pos = substr($value,$a-1,strlen($value));
        }
   }

  return $pos;
}

echo convertVal("0000980");
```

Comment: This will fail if the value is 0000980

Comment: you are right, i'll edit it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$num = '0.000098000';
$newNum = preg_replace('/^[0\.]+/', '', $num);
```

The `$newNum` will contain the required output (`98000` in the case above) after replacing all the `0` and `.` from the starting.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to take a string, split it by a comma and remove spaces , multiply by 1000000  then put it back together. Try doing this:

```
$str = "0.000098, 0.000854";
echo implode(",",array_map(function($a){ return 1000000 * trim($a); },explode(",", $str)));
```

or in a slightly more readable form:

```
$parts = explode(",", $str);
$parts = array_map(function($a) { return 1000000 * trim($a); }, $parts);
echo implode(",", $parts);
```